# what did is difference between java and kotlin about visibility modifiers?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

[image]

This is what the official document says. But when I do something like this:

```
var human : Human? = null
```

and decompile it into java code, I find it actually was

```
@Nullable
private Human human;
```

and it's no use to write this

```
public var human : Human? = null
```

but when I write this:

```
lateinit var human : Human
```

it become public this time

```
@NotNull
public Human human;
```

it was a big problem when I use `Dagger2`

in Dagger2  the property be injected must be public, but if i write `var human : Human? = null`
it will fail to build.

Comment: just say what you want broh

Comment: Don't just comparing java and kotlin. What you have to do is learn how to use kotlin..

If you want to learn about visibility in kotlin, then just do what document said. no need to compare it with the decompiled code

Comment: as long as i use kotlin, i dont find anything wrong with the document. It's working as what the document said

Comment: @ zihadrizkyef  in Dagger2 i the property be injected must be private, but if i write var human : Human? = null it will fail to build. so  it confused me . otherwise, i won't compare java and kotlin in this way

Comment: the document say that is was public but actually it was private. it actually was wrong . right?

Comment: Well sorry about that.. I think the problem is in your converter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slove my problem by myself.

Actually , what kotlin's public mean is private + getter and setter , private is jsut private has no getter and setter.  The official document didn't explain that clearly.

So , it add some explain at the chapter `Calling Kotlin from Java`  it means  if you want your properties is public , you can use 
`@JvmField` or 
`lateinit var`

It's my fault , i didn't  reading the document carefullly

Answer (score 0):

> in Dagger2 i the property be injected must be private

Are you sure? AFAIK the field needs to be `public`, and `lateinit var human: Human` should be fine.

Comment: yes, you're right.  the field needs to be public, and ```lateinit var human: Human``` is fine . But ```var human : Human? = null``` is not fine

Answer (score 0):

1. "The default visibility is `public`" just means that if you don't specify visibility, it's the same as specifying `public`.
2. Property corresponds to getter and setter methods (`getHuman()` and `setHuman()`) in decompiled code, not really to the field `human`.
3. The documentation talking about visibility *from Kotlin*, which isn't the same as visibility according to JVM (and can't be, because JVM doesn't have `internal` visibility). JVM visibility is just implementation details (so far as this documentation is concerned).

From 2 and 3 together, the cited documentation says absolutely nothing about even existence of the backing field, never mind its visibility, which is what Dagger cares about. Instead, it's documented in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html:

1. In the first section, "Properties":

   > A **private** field, with the same name as the property name (only for properties with backing fields).
2. In "Instance fields":

   > If you need to expose a Kotlin property as a field in Java, you need to annotate it with the @JvmField annotation. **The field will have the same visibility as the underlying property.**

   and

   > Late-Initialized properties are also exposed as fields. The visibility of the field will be **the same as the visibility of lateinit property setter**.